# Does Unarmored Defense stack with a staff of power and the Bladesong class feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, barbarian

I'm playing a level 10 blade singer wizard with one level into barbarian for unarmored defense. I have a +5 Dex modifier, a +5 Int modifier, and a +4 Con modifier. I also have a staff of power that gives +2 to AC.

My total AC would be 4+5+10=19 from *Unarmored Defense*, +2 from the *staff of power*, and +5 from the *Blade Singer* arcane tradition, for a total of 19+2+5= **26 AC**. Is my math correct?

Comment: You have 20 DEX, 18 CON and 20 INT at level 10? Insane stat rolls or homebrew?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Don't expect an answer: "Last seen Jul 14 '18 at 18:32"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your math is correct.

Initially your unarmored defense is 10 + Dex + Con. The [Staff of Power](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Staff%20of%20Power#content) has a constant effect, so that boosts your AC by +2.

Your normal AC is therefore = 10 + 5 (Dex) + 4 (Con) + 2 = **21** AC.

During a Bladesong, which lasts 1 minute, you add +5 (Int) to your AC, for a total of 21 + 5 = **26** AC!

Answer (score 5):

Your unarmoured defence AC when Bladesong isn't active is:
10 + 4 Con + 5 Dex + 2 Magic Item = 21 AC

With Bladesong active you gain +5 Int to your AC which makes it 26 AC. Keep in mind that if you use your Staff of Power to make an attack with both hands, **your Bladesong will end early!**

You must have rolled very well for your stats considering you have 20 Dex, 18 Con, 20 Int.